# Weird behaviour doing rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pests.co.il/%ee%e0%ee%f8%e9%ed/%e4%e3%e1%f8%fa_%fa%e9%f7%f0%e9%ed_/29$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I enter the following URL everything works fine and the redirect works:

```
http://www.pests.co.il/?one_art=29
```

If I enter the following URL it redirects to the wrong non existent URL:

```
http://www.pests.co.il/index.php?one_art=29
```

redirects to:

```
    http://www.pests.co.il/%25ee%25e0%25ee%25f8%25e9%25ed/%25e4%25e3%25e1%25f8%25fa_%25fa%25e9%25f7%25f0%25e9%25ed_/29index.php?one_art=29
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I deleted all other rewrites to make sure it is nothing else interfering but this is still happening.

********* EDIT ************

Much better now. However still unable to rewrite if the is only the query string without the index.php: If I do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$ 
RewriteRule (.*) pests.co.ilמאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Then the url with index.php rewrites properly but the one without the index.php does not change.

If I do this then nothing works. Notice the first 3 lines are the same as the above I just added another 2 lines to deal with url's without the index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$ 
RewriteRule (.*) pests.co.ilמאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,NE,L]  

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$ 
RewriteRule (.*) pests.co.ilמאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas why this is happening?

Yes.

- `(.*)` captures the part of the url after the domain and optional slash and before the query string to Group 1.
- `...ed_/29$1` adds the content of Group 1 at the end of the rewritten url
- In the case of `http://www.pests.co.il/?one_art=29`, Group 1 is empty, so nothing gets added
- In the case of `http://www.pests.co.il/index.php?one_art=29`, Group 1 is `index.php` and gets added after the ``...ed_/29`

Comment: So are you saying I should I remove the (.*) from the rule? I tried that already and it didn't work as expected. Maybe I also need a different end to the line with the rule? Something instead of $1 ?

Comment: I'm not saying what you should do, as I have no idea what you want to do. :) I just answered the question "Why is this happening?"

Comment: Good explanation, @Allon you need to define your requirements clearly.

Comment: Ok, not sure what is not clear. I want it to redirect to:
    http://www.pests.co.il/%ee%e0%ee%f8%e9%ed/%e4%e3%e1%f8%fa_%fa%e9%f7%f0%e9%ed_/29

And if index.php is in the url it does not do that, it redirects to the wrong URL.

Comment: Also, sometimes the URL it redirects to is:
    http://www.pests.co.il/home/pestscoi/public_html/www.pests.co.il/

I say sometimes because for some reason it is redirecting to an unexpected URL and usually it is to the one I just pasted though today for some reason it is redirecting to the URL I put in the original post, so the behaviour is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

By default mod_rewrite will escape special characters such as % -- which becomes %25 so %ee becomes %25ee etc.  Read up on the [noescape flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne).  Your rule should have the flags `[R=301,NE,L]`

Comment: Thanks but this is not causing the issue as it is redirecting to a very specific URL which I did not define. It is either adding the query string to the end of the new url or going to public html folder.

Comment: Now I am confused.  @zx81 explained how the redirect worked only omitting this escaping issue.  I just took your second URI and when through your rules to convert it into what I thought that it would.  then when I compared this to your quoted value, it was the same byte-for-byte.  So yes your rules did define this target.  You just don't understand the explanations given.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but I am telling you it is redirecting to a different URL. Either with public_html in the URL and the www.pests... twice or adding the query string to the end as in my first example. What part of the explanations here tell me why this is happening and how to write the rules in a way that they will redirect as desired? :)

Comment: `http://www.pests.co.il/index.php?one_art=29` should redirect to `http://www.pests.co.il/%25ee%25e0%25ee%25f8%25e9%25ed/%25e4%25e3%25e1%25f8%25fa_%25fa%25e9%25f7%25f0%25e9%25ed_/29index.php?one_art=29` according to your rules, and this is what you said it redirected to.  What is your issue?

Comment: no, it should redirect to:
    http://www.pests.co.il/%25ee%25e0%25ee%25f8%25e9%25ed/%25e4%25e3%25e1%25f8%25fa‌​_%25fa%25e9%25f7%25f0%25e9%25ed_/29
without the index.php?one_art=29 at the end

Comment: Well if you want that then don't include the `$1` at the end of the substitution string, because that is what you are asking mod_rewrite to do!!!!

Comment: Thanks!

Much better now. However still unable to rewrite if the is only the query string without the index.php:


If I do this:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pests.co.il/מאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,NE,L]

Then the url with index.php rewrites properly.

Comment: If I do this then nothing works:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pests.co.il/מאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,NE,L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} one_art=29$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pests.co.il/מאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,NE,L]

Comment: @Allon, don't try to put this stuff in comments -- the markup is too limiting.  Please edit your Q and append the extra details.  Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a `DirectoryIndex index.php`.  And have fun destroying your cockroaches

Comment: I thought of doing it via php but the problem is it isa clients site with a crm that is unknown to me and I don't want to start editing the files it is too risky.

Does my code look good to you? I mean, is the problem I am facing really unexplainable? I thought maybe it was something I am missing like the wrong character or something like that?

Comment: TerryE, maybe you can tell me why this is causing a redirect loop from both url's (with or without the index.php):

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^one_art=29$
RewriteRule (.*) /מאמרים/הדברת_תיקנים_/29? [R=301,L]